# get pretty json out put when using rails render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I currently include the following line at the end of my rails controller method to out put json data

```
 render :json => paragraph_hash
```

Can I modify this line somehow, so that that it nicely formats the output json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're really intent on formatting your JSON output, the simplest solution would be [pretty_generate](http://apidock.com/ruby/JSON/pretty_generate), though how "pretty" it makes JSON strings is subjective.  In your case, you could implement it in a similar manner to this:

`render :json => JSON.pretty_generate(paragraph_hash`